# Bind multiple host directories to same container path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Is there a way to bind/ mount multiple host directories to same container path?
for example:
have something like this in Docker-Compose.yml

```
  ...volumes:
     ... - ./path/on/host/directory1:path/on/container/directory
     ... - ./path/on/host/directory2:path/on/container/directory
```

I get files from second Binding (./path/on/host/directory2:path/on/container/directory) successfully, but do not get any files from first binding (directory1) on container.

Comment: No (no more than it's possible to mount multiple devices to the same directory outside of Docker).  What semantics are you expecting if the same file is in both host directories, or if you create a new file?

Comment: Thanks Dave! makes sense.